# Datatables 1.10 - HTML5 "data-order" or "data-filter" not working

Tags: datatables

I am building the datatable dynamically with json objects. I have few columns that have `<input>` and `<select>` HTML elements. The global search or the sort doesn't work for these HTML elements. Hence I thought of using data-order and data-filter attributes. In the `createdCell` callback function I add these attributes to the `<td>`, but sorting or searching is still not working on those columns.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I think you need to elaborate :) Try edit an example of your code into the question. It is more easy to deliver a satisfying answer when we have some code demonstrating the problem, and then produce some code where the problem is solved.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and found no solution yet and wanted to add to OP's question. In my case, my createdCell function looks like this: `createdCell: function (td, data) { $(td).attr('data-filter', data ? 'Active' : 'Inactive').attr('data-order', data ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'); }` where data is a boolean for an active flag. my cell is rendered like so: `<td data-filter="Active" data-order="Active" class="sorting_1"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-label="Active"></i></td>` but the sorting and searching on that column do not work.